# Bad indentation in user created environment

Tags: environments, indentation

I created an environment, and I have a problem with the first paragraph indentation. This is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools}



\begin{document}

\newif\ifrisposte
\rispostetrue %togli il commento se vuoi i risultati

\newcounter{numquesito}

\newenvironment{domanda}[1]{\stepcounter{numquesito}\par\bigskip\noindent\textbf{\thenumquesito}. \textbf{#1.}\par\medskip\noindent%
}%{\relax}

\ifrisposte
  \newenvironment{risposta}[1]{\par\medskip\noindent {\ttfamily \fontseries{b}\selectfont [#1]}}{\par\bigskip}
\else
  \excludecomment{risposta}
\fi


\begin{domanda}{Title}
Bad indentation in the first line. Then everything is ok in the second and subsequent lines.

The second paraagraph has a different indentation.
\end{domanda}

\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

What can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Why do you use `\noindent`?

Comment: I would like to have no indentation in the first paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the “begin part” of `domanda` starts a paragraph, so the endline after `\begin{domanda}{Title}` becomes a space in output.

Add `\ignorespaces` at the end. I also suggest some other changes to the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{comment}

\newcounter{numquesito}

\newenvironment{domanda}[1]
 {%
  \stepcounter{numquesito}%
  \par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}%
  \noindent\textbf{\thenumquesito\ #1.}\par\nopagebreak\medskip\noindent
  \ignorespaces
 }
 {\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}}

\newenvironment{risposta}[1]
 {%
  \par\addvspace{\medskipamount}%
  \noindent{\fontseries{b}\ttfamily [#1] }\ignorespaces
 }
 {\par\addvspace{\bigskipamount}}

%%%
\newif\ifrisposte
\AtBeginDocument{\ifrisposte\else\excludecomment{risposta}\fi}
%%%

\rispostetrue %togli il commento se vuoi i risultati

\begin{document}

\begin{domanda}{Title}
Bad indentation in the first line. Then everything is ok in the second and subsequent lines.

The second paraagraph has a different indentation.
\end{domanda}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of “hard” vertical spaces, I suggest `\addvspace` that doesn't accumulate them, but just uses the largest one. Also `\nopagebreak` is needed after setting the title.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know how to use \ignorespaces